# Entity Framework 5 dbContext object hydration

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, entity-framework-5

We are trying to write a WCF Cache service which uses ef5 to get data from the db.

the problem is with serializing a very simple model.

*Consider this.*

we have 5000 products in the db. Each product has an associated manufacturer lets say there are 2 manufacturers.

for our cache we turn the proxy creation off so that when it is serialized we don't get every object in the db. we then write

`dbCtx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var products = dbCtx.Products.Include("Manufacturers").ToDictionary(x=>x.PartNo);`

this will get all 5000 products into our cache.

we then have a wcf method

`Product GetProduct(string PartNo);`

if we call GetProduct("MyPart") the returned object is the part we want with one of the two manufacturers attached great.

here is the catch The associated manufacturer has a navigation property back to products.
hanging off the navigation property are 2500 other products.

this would make for a very large serialized object.

What appears to be happening. The 5000 products are retrieved from the database by `dbCtx`.
once it has created all the 5000 products and put them on the context it creates the Manufacturers. during the creation of the manufacturers it spots the product navigation property and populates it with all the products from it's local context. If ProxyCreationEnabled is true then it puts a proxy object on the navigation property instead. What we would like it to do is ignore the objects it already know about and provide a null or empty collection so that we can serialize just what we want.

I did some work in EF 4 around this area and remember that when attaching a detached object there was a call you could make so that your detached object became associated with all the other objects in the context.

I think this call is being made on our behalf by the dbcontext and i want to stop it.

Any suggestions about where to look for more info or how to stop it would be very helpfull.

Comment: Consider using DTOs for sending over WCF. If you use AutoMapper, this will reduce the pain of converting to and from your DTO.

Comment: @Aron I had not come across the term DTO till now. so a google and the WIKI page tells me all about DTO. So my Understanding of a DTO is they are simple objects with just Set and Get for the properties no logic other than how to store their data. This is exactly what we have. Are you suggesting new Manufacturers objects with no back link to Products thus avoiding the extra product objects.

Comment: The term DTO stands for Data Transfer Object. The objects are specifically for transferring across networks (serialization). In this case you would just do the same classes (without the backlinks). You might want to read up on how to configure AutoMapper to put them back in.